# Prove that there are $0<c_1 < c_2<1$ s.t. $\frac{1}{g'(c_1)}+\frac{1}{g'(c_2)}=2$ . The same for $g'(c_1)g'(c_2)=1$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Given $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on  $(0,1)$,
>   $g(0)=0$, and $g(1)=1$.
>
> 1) Prove that there exist $0<c_1<c_2<1$ such that
>   $$\frac{1}{g'(c_1)}+\frac{1}{g'(c_2)}=2.$$
>
> 2) Prove that there exist $0<c_1<c_2<1$ such that 
>   $$g'(c_1)g'(c_2)=1.$$

I am thinking if Mean Value Theorem would help, but Mean Value theorem could only prove that in interval (0,1) there exists $g'(c)=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part see [Prove there exist $0\le c_1<c_2<\dots<c_n\le1$ where $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{f'(c_k)}=n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008760/prove-there-exist-0-le-c-1c-2-dotsc-n-le1-where-sum-k-1n-frac1fc-k?rq=1)

Now we show that there are $0< c_1<c_2< 1$ such that $g'(c_1) g'(c_2)=1$.

Since $g(1)-g(0)=1$, by the MVT there is at least one $c\in (0,1)$ such that $g'(c)=1$. We may assume that $c$ is the only one, otherwise the claim is trivially true. We have three cases.

1) $g'(x)\leq 1$ on $(0,1)$. Then we should have $g'(x)<1$ in $(0,c)$ and $(c,1)$ and by the MVT, 
$$g(c)-g(0)<c-0\;,\;g(1)-g(c)<1-c\implies 1=g(1)-g(0)<(1-c)+c=1$$
Contradiction.

2) $g'(x)\geq 1$ on $(0,1)$. Then we should have $g'(x)>1$ in $(0,c)$ and $(c,1)$ and by the MVT, 
$$g(c)-g(0)>c-0\;,\;g(1)-g(c)>1-c\implies 1=g(1)-g(0)>(1-c)+c=1$$
Contradiction.

3) There are $s,t\in (0,1)$ such that $a=g'(t)<1$ and $b=g'(s)>1$.
Then, by [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), $g'$ assumes between $s$ and $t$ all the values in $(1-r,1+r)\subset (g'(t),g'(s))$ for some $r\in (0,1)$.
Now note that $1-r<\frac{1}{1+\frac{r}{2}}<1+\frac{r}{2}<1+r$, hence there exist $c_1,c_2\in (0,1)$ such that 
$$g'(c_1)g'(c_2)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{r}{2}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{r}{2}\right)=1$$
and we are done.

Comment: Is there another way around this without usage of Darboux theorem? The context of the question is where one has just learnt Mean/Intermediate/Extreme Value Theorem. Thank you, nonetheless!

Comment: @dormacus Since $g$ is differentiable and not $C^1$, I think that here we need some version of Darboux theorem. Anyway the proof of this result depends only on the MVT and the IVT. So I don't think I am out of the context. See the proof here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: @dormacus May I know where this problem comes from?

Comment: @RobertZ $g'(c_1)g'(c_2)$ can be found easily once we are able to prove $\frac{1}{g'(c_1)}+\frac{1}{g'(c_2)=2}$

$\frac{g'(c_1)+g'(c_2)}{g'(c_1)g'(c_2}=\frac{1}{g'(c_1)}+\frac{1}{g'(c_2)}=2$

Comment: @kevinbobbkoh Yes, but it is not so straightforward, you have to use something like my point 3).

Comment: @RobertZ I believe it is adapted from a textbook

Comment: @kevinbobkoh Thanks I did not think about multiplying it together!

Comment: @dormacus Then after the multiplication what do you get? $g'(c_1)g'(c_2)=1?$

Comment: @RobertZ yes. However that requires proving $g'(c_1)+g'(c_2)=2$ which I am also kind of stuck as using MVT, I end up with $\frac{f(c)-2c*f(c)+c}{c*(1-c)}$ I am unsure why.

Comment: @dormacus Yes, what I am trying to say is that it is not so straightforward, to show 2) from 1) . You always need  something like my point 3).